# How to remember what selection from a picker, Im using xamarin.plugins.settings by montemagno and i don't know how to get the right syntax

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

the value or string is getting saved but the selection on the picker on the main page itself is not getting saved. when i re open my app the picker is in empty.  I don't know the syntax how to use a picker.
npicker1 = nlocation1;

xaml:

```
  <Picker x:Name="drainlocationPicker1" Title="Drain Location" 
                 Grid.Column="1" SelectedIndexChanged="drain1Handle_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

//code behind

//list of selection:

```
 public SettingsPage()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    nquantity();
    list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("Right1");
    list.Add("Right2");
    list.Add("Right3");
    list.Add("Right4");

    //picker1 example selection
    void n1Handle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
     nlocation1 = (string)nlocationPicker1.SelectedItem;
    //if picker1 is not empty then show n2picker
    if (nlocationPicker1.SelectedItem != null)
    {
    nPicker2.IsVisible = true;
    Picker1.IsEnabled = false;

    nlocationPicker2.Items.Remove((string)nlocationPicker1.SelectedItem);

    nlocationPicker3.Items.Remove((string)nlocationPicker1.SelectedItem);
    }
    //supposed to save picker selection
    void settingsaveButton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {


    bool isNameEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameEntry.Text);
    if (isNameEmpty == true)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Enter Name", "PLEASE", "OK");
    }
    else if (nlocationPicker1.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Error1", "Please select your country.", "Ok");
        nPicker1.Focus();
    }

    else
    {
    Navigation.PushModalAsync(new HomePage());

    //put nlocation1 to nPicker1
    // npicker=nlocation1???
    Settings.n1LocationSettings = nlocation1;
    Settings.n2LocationSettings = nlocation2;
    Settings.n3LocationSettings = nlocation3; 

    }
```

Comment: please edit your post to include a [mcve].  The code you've posted is both incomplete and uncompilable.

Comment: i've added more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set a default value to a picker, you can use:

1.`npicker.SelectedItem = nlocation1;`

2.Set the index: `npicker.SelectedIndex = 2;`

3.In xaml:

```
<Picker  x:Name="drainlocationPicker1" 
                Title="Drain Location" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                ItemsSource="{Binding myList}"
                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Title}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject}"        
                />
```

Note:

> A Picker can be initialized to display a specific item by setting the
>   SelectedIndex or SelectedItem properties. However, these properties
>   must be set after initializing the ItemsSource collection.

The document is here: [picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource#responding-to-item-selection)

I don't know what is `Settings.Drain1LocationSettings` in your project. I create a simple sample for you.

In xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Picker x:Name="drainlocationPicker1" Title="Drain Location"  SelectedIndexChanged="DrainlocationPicker1_SelectedIndexChanged" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
</StackLayout>
```

In code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    private static ISettings AppSettings =>  CrossSettings.Current;

    public static string LastPickValue
    {
        get => AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(nameof(LastPickValue), string.Empty);
        set => AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(nameof(LastPickValue), value);
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("Right1");
        list.Add("Right2");
        list.Add("Right3");
        list.Add("Right4");

        drainlocationPicker1.ItemsSource = list;

        //Set the default value
        drainlocationPicker1.SelectedItem = LastPickValue;
    }

    private void DrainlocationPicker1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string nlocation1 = (string)drainlocationPicker1.SelectedItem;

        LastPickValue = nlocation1;
    }
}
```

You can use the `LastPickValue` to store the value user picked and set it to the picker next time.

By using plugin.setting, you should define the `LastPickValue`  in following way:

```
public static string LastPickValue
{
    get => AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(nameof(LastPickValue), string.Empty);
    set => AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(nameof(LastPickValue), value);
}
```

I uploaded my sample [here](https://github.com/XfHua/using-of-plugin.setting-xamarin.forms) and you can check it, let me know if it works.

Comment: I want picker equal to  what user selected. so this is when user select it goes to nlocation1 = (string)nlocationPicker1.SelectedItem;      drainlocationPicker1.SelectedItem = drainlocation1;  i want picker to equal what's in Settings.Drain1LocationSettings.
                Settings.Drain1LocationSettings = drainlocation1;

Comment: I ran your code. I'm still trying to understand it but it's right. it's what i want to do.  follow up question in a couple of days.

Comment: @hypnocool You can see the Plugin.settings's document [here](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/SettingsPlugin/). Save the value in the setter of the property.

Comment: Hua <Entry x:Name="nameEntry"/>  if I want to remember what was entered on Entry.... will this work.. nameEntry.text = LastPickValue.  Will is remember the last entry type?

Comment: @hypnocool It should work. You can open a new thread and add the code there 
then I can help you.

Comment: i have one...some are suggesting data binding or calling a method, like the selected index change but for entry. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56713755/why-cant-it-remember-last-text-entered-in-entry-in-xamarin/56729258#56729258

Comment: @hypnocool You should save the value at the Handle_Unfocused event like Argon said. Anything you don't understand? Unfocused event fires when you finish input text in the entry.

Comment: @hypnocool The only problem to you is when you want to save the value?