# Why Can't It remember last text entered in entry in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to remember what was last entry entered and outputting it on Label to check if it works.  I'm using Xam.Plugins.settings by Montemagno.

I tried Settings.

```
using Plugin.Settings;
using Plugin.Settings.Abstractions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App424
{
    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
// by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
public static string LastPickName
{
    get => AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(nameof(LastPickName), string.Empty);
    set => AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(nameof(LastPickName), value);
}

string name;
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();


/*works if i force a text
nameEntry.Text = "You";
LastPickName = nameEntry.Text;

nameLabel.Text = LastPickName;*/

name = nameEntry.Text;
LastPickName = name

nameLabel.Text = LastPickName;
}


}
}
```

Label is empty.It's not showing the data supposed to be saved .

Answer (score 1):

Because the Label component is not bounded to the variable, it just gets it value when you did `nameEntry.Text = "You";` e no further more.

To make it works you have basically two choices:

**1. Set the value to the label on every change;**

Just set the values or variable like Argon suggests in his answer

**2. Bind the page (View) to an Observable object**, then the view will listen to every change on your observable object (often a View Model) and react to this (changing it's self Text value, for example).

I guess what you're intending to do is the second one. So you can create a public string full property on your page's code behind and bind the instance of your page to itself. Like this:

```
   <Label Text="{Binding MyStringProperty}"
  .../>
```

and binding:

```
 private string myStringProperty;
    public string MyStringProperty
    {
        get { return myStringProperty; }
        set 
        {
            myStringProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyStringProperty)); // Notify that there was a change on this property
        }
    }
```

If this still does not make sense/work for you, I would suggest you spend sometime to master [Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/), it won't take long to learn and it is crucial in Xamarin Forms.
Alternatively watch [James's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pr03CYqhFr4) on DataBinding.

Answer (score 0):

Use a method to set the value to the setting.

```
<Entry Placeholder="Name" x:Name="name" Unfocused="Handle_Unfocused"/>
```

```
void Handle_Unfocused(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.FocusEventArgs e)
{
  LastPickName = name.Text;
}
```

Comment: is there another method i Can use?  what does Handle_Unfocused do, like does it get invoke when something is unfocuse?

Answer (score 0):

Using Properties dictionary to store simple values, then using Unfocused event to get the last text from Entry, please take care Entry.Text is null or empty when unfocus.

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Entry x:Name="entry1" Unfocused="Entry1_Unfocused" />
        <Label
            x:Name="label1"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>


 private void Entry1_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry1.Text))
        {
            Application.Current.Properties["myTextValue"] = entry1.Text;
            label1.Text = Application.Current.Properties["myTextValue"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

[image]